# SQLite Android update field from other fields

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to update an integer field in my SQLite database by combining three other integer fields but I need to also prefix two the of the other fields with a zero if the length of the field value is 1.

This is a routine I am trying to do via the Upgrade Database method in my DBAdapter Class.

So I need to change this current update :

```
if (newVersion==2) {
  populatesql = "update " + DB_TABLE + 
                " set field1="+ COL_FIELD2 +
                " || " +
                COL_FIELD3 + 
                " || " + 
                COL_FIELD4;
}
```

to something like this (yes I know the the prefixzero would not work as it needs String not integer but I tried it with String and made it static but it did not work)

```
if (newVersion==2) {
  populatesql = "update " + DB_TABLE + 
                " set field1="+ COL_FIELD2 +
                " || " +
                prefixzero(COL_FIELD3) + 
                " || " + 
                prefixzero(COL_FIELD4);
}

public String prefixzero(String number) {
    String result = Integer.toString(number);

    // Log.d("PREFIX", "result starts with this = "+result);
    if (result.length() >1 ) {
      // Log.d("PREFIX", "NO ZEROES HERE");
      return Integer.toString(number);
    }

   String zeroprefix = "";
   zeroprefix = "0"+result;
   // Log.d("PREFIX", zeroprefix);

   return zeroprefix ;
}
```

The database fields are declared as follows:

```
public static final String COL_FIELD4 = "day";
public static final String COL_FIELD3 = "month";
public static final String COL_FIELD2 = "year";
public static final String COL_FIELD1 = "long_date";
```

This is the error I get leaving out the spaces. It is as thought without the spaces the field names are simply joined together. The code used is below this error.

```
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.uk.common.myapp/co.uk.common.myapp.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: yearmonthday: update Log set long_date= yearmonthday
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: yearmonthday: update Log set long_date= yearmonthday
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at co.uk.shieldstothemax.blastedneighbours.DBAdapter$DBHelper.onUpgrade(DBAdapter.java:68)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at co.uk.shieldstothemax.blastedneighbours.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:87)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at co.uk.shieldstothemax.blastedneighbours.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:123)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 07:34:00.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18332):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
```

Cod in the onUpgrade method:

```
if (newVersion==2) {

                 populatesql = "update "+ DB_TABLE +" set long_date= "+getDateStr(COL_FIELD2,COL_FIELD3,COL_FIELD4);                
                }
```

The getDateStr:

```
public static String getDateStr(String year, String month,String day) {
        return year+ prefixfieldzero(month)+ prefixfieldzero(day);
     }
```

the prefixfieldzero :

```
public static String prefixfieldzero(String number) {
            String result = String.valueOf(number);
          //  Log.d("PREFIX", "result starts with this = "+result);
            if (result.length() >1 ) {
             // Log.d("PREFIX", "NO ZEROES HERE");
             return number;
             }

           String zerofieldprefix = "";
           zerofieldprefix = "0"+result;
          // Log.d("PREFIX", zeroprefix);

              return zerofieldprefix ;
        }
```

Here is my DBAdapter :

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DBAdapter {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "TABLE";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Log";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+DB_TABLE+ 
                " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                       "type_id INTEGER, " +" hour INTEGER, " + 
                         "min INTEGER , " +" info VARCHAR,"+"image_desc VARCHAR, "+ 
                       "day INTEGER, "+"month INTEGER,  "+ "year INTEGER,"+" second INTEGER,long_date INTEGER ,date_time_long INTEGER NOT NULL "+");" ;


        public static final String COL_TYPE = "type_id";
        public static final String COL_HOUR = "hour";
        public static final String COL_MIN = "min";
        public static final String COL_SEC = "second";
        public static final String COL_IMAGE = "image_desc";

        public static final String COL_DAY = "day";
        public static final String COL_MON = "month";
        public static final String COL_YEAR = "year";
        public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
        public static final String COL_LONG_DATE = "long_date";
        public static final String COL_INFO = "info";   
        public static final String COL_ID = "_id";

        private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
        private DBHelper mDBHelper;
        private Context mCtx;

        private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
            public DBHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                Log.v("OLDDBVERSION", "Old version="+String.valueOf(oldVersion));
                Log.v("NEWDBVERSION", "New version="+String.valueOf(newVersion));
                //String upgradesql = null;
                String populatesql = null;
                if (newVersion==2) {

                 populatesql = "update "+ DB_TABLE +" set long_date= "+getDateStr(COL_YEAR,COL_MON,COL_DAY);                
                }
                if (populatesql !=null) {
                    //db.execSQL(upgradesql);               
                    if (populatesql !=null) {

                        db.execSQL(populatesql);
                    }
                }



        } 
   }

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }

        //OPEN METHOD AND CLOSE METHOD
        public DBAdapter open()
        {
            mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
            mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //important
            return this;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            mDBHelper.close();
        }

        //INSERT AND DELETE
        public long createLog(String info,String image, Integer type,Integer hour,Integer mins,Integer sec,Integer day,Integer month,Integer year,Long longdate,Long date)
        {
            ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
            v.put(COL_TYPE, type);
            v.put(COL_INFO, info);
            v.put(COL_IMAGE, image);
            v.put(COL_HOUR, hour);
            v.put(COL_SEC, sec);
            v.put(COL_MIN, mins);
            v.put(COL_DAY, day);
            v.put(COL_MON, month);
            v.put(COL_YEAR, year);
            v.put(COL_DATE, date);
            v.put(COL_LONG_DATE, longdate);

            return mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, v);
        }

        public boolean deleteLogRec(long id)
        {
            return mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COL_ID + "="+ id, null)>0;
        }

        public boolean deleteAllLogs()
        {
            return mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null)>0;
        }

        //get all bookmark
        public Cursor GetAllLogs(Integer i,String sortfield)
        {
            String sorted = "";
            if (i == 1 ) {
                sorted = "DESC";
            } else if (i == 2) {
                sorted = "ASC";
            } 


            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_TYPE,COL_IMAGE, COL_INFO,COL_IMAGE,COL_HOUR,COL_SEC,COL_MIN,COL_DAY,COL_MON,COL_YEAR,COL_SORT_DATE},
                            null, null, null, null, COL_DATE+" "+sorted);
        }

        public Cursor allrecords() {

            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_TYPE,COL_IMAGE, COL_INFO,COL_IMAGE,COL_HOUR,COL_SEC,COL_MIN,COL_DAY,COL_MON,COL_YEAR,COL_SORT_DATE},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
        }





        //get a specific log by id
        public Cursor getLog(long id)
        {
            Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_TYPE,COL_IMAGE, COL_INFO,COL_IMAGE,COL_HOUR,COL_SEC,COL_MIN,COL_DAY,COL_MON,COL_YEAR},
                    COL_ID + "=" + id,
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor!=null)
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            return mCursor;
        }

        //finally update the log
        public boolean updateLog(long id, String uinfo, String uimage,Integer utype,Integer uhour,Integer usec,Integer umin,Integer uday,Integer umonth,Integer uyear,Long ulongdate,Long udate)
        {
            ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
            v.put(COL_TYPE, utype);
            v.put(COL_INFO, uinfo);
            v.put(COL_IMAGE, uimage);
            v.put(COL_HOUR, uhour);
            v.put(COL_SEC, usec);
            v.put(COL_MIN, umin);
            v.put(COL_DAY, uday);
            v.put(COL_MON, umonth);
            v.put(COL_YEAR, uyear);
            v.put(COL_DATE, udate);
            v.put(COL_SORT_DATE, ulongdate);

            return mDB.update(DB_TABLE, v, COL_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
        }   

        public static String prefixfieldzero(String number) {
            String result = String.valueOf(number);
          //  Log.d("PREFIX", "result starts with this = "+result);
            if (result.length() >1 ) {
             // Log.d("PREFIX", "NO ZEROES HERE");
             return number;
             }

           String zerofieldprefix = "";
           zerofieldprefix = "0"+result;
          // Log.d("PREFIX", zeroprefix);

              return zerofieldprefix ;
        }

    public static String getDateStr(String year, String month,String day) {
            return year+ prefixfieldzero(month)+ prefixfieldzero(day);
         }


}
```

Tried to run the SQL as per your latest answer but get this error :

```
03-01 00:20:05.379: E/AndroidRuntime(19060): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AS": syntax error: update TABLE AS TABLE_Temp1 set long_date = (select year || substr('00' || month ,-2,2  ) || substr('00' || ,day, -2 ,2)  from Log AS TABLE_Temp2 where TABLE_Temp1.id=TABLE_Temp2.id
```

Current SQL used to update long date to the combination of the year month and day:

```
populatesql = "update "+DB_TABLE + " AS LogTemp1 set long_date = (select year || substr('00' || month ,-2,2  ) || substr('00' || ,day, -2 ,2)  from "+DB_TABLE+" AS LogTemp2 where LogTemp1.id=LogTemp2.id   "  ;
```

I have also tried it as follows:

```
populatesql = "update "+DB_TABLE + " AS LogTemp1 set long_date = (select year || substr('00' || month ,-2,2  ) || substr('00' || ,day, -2 ,2)  from "+DB_TABLE+" AS LogTemp2 where **LogTemp1._id=LogTemp2._id**   "  ;
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what is || supposed to do on strings ?

Comment: @njzk2 || is for concatenation of strings in SQLite

Comment: Define "did not work". Your code, while messy, should work fine. what is the value of COL_FIELD3

Comment: Sorry what I meant to mean by it didn't work is that the prefix did not get written to FIELD1. I have updated the post as there should have been a FIELD2 FIELD3 and FIELD4. FIELD3 is the month and FIELD4 is the day. So I am trying to go from 201311 to 20130101

Comment: I would suggest an ORM, if third party libraries are permitted in your project

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance , what is an ORM? should what I have done work? The COL_FIELDS are define to refer to the real field names in the database table. Would this make any difference ? I will edit the post to include these

Comment: I would advise not piecing the SQL together as strings like this! Try using the update command found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update

Comment: ing0 - I have tried to use the update method you suggest which requires ContentValues to be set , the only problem I have with this is that the ContentValues does not allow me to assign values from only field(s) to the one I am updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally got, what you want. You need an update statement that updates each row based on its current values. Of course you cannot call from the SQLite database to a function within your Java code. Thus everything must be done within your UPDATE statement within SQLite itself.

Given that, your statement should look like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable AS table1 
SET date = 
    (SELECT year || 
            substr('00' || month, -2, 2) || 
            substr('00' || day, -2, 2) 
     FROM yourTable AS table2 
     WHERE table1.id = table2.id);
```

You only have to replace the names I use here with the names you actually use and make a valid Java String of it.

The `substr('00' || month, -2, 2)` statements does what the `lpad` statement (which is not available in SQLite) of other database engines would do.

You can read it like this: Concatenate two zeros with a number, and take the rightmost two characters of the resulting string. The `-2` means, start the substring count from the right edge, and the `2`means take two characters as the resulting substring.

This `lpad` replacement is based on [a blogpost](http://verysimple.com/2010/01/12/sqlite-lpad-rpad-function/) by [Jason Hinkle](https://twitter.com/jasonhinkle).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that COL_FIELD2... are String values, why not do something like this?

```
     if (newVersion==2) {
       populatesql = "update " + DB_TABLE + 
                     " set field1 = " + getDateStr(COL_FIELD2, COL_FIELD3, COL_FIELD4);
     }

     getDateStr(String year, String month,String day) {
        return year + prefixzero(month) + prefixzero(day);
     }

     public String prefixzero(String number) {
        //Log.d("PREFIX", "result starts with this = "+result);
        if (number.length() > 1) {
           //Log.d("PREFIX", "NO ZEROES HERE");
           return number;
        }            
        number = "0" + number;
        //Log.d("PREFIX", zeroprefix);            
        return zeroprefix ;
     }
```

If they are `int`-values you could use the following `prefixzero()` method instead (and of course adapt the method signature of `getDateStr()` as well:

```
     public String prefixzero(int number) {
        if (number > 9) {
           return Integer.toString(number);
        }
        return "0" + number;
     }
```

Comment: As mentioned the fields that represent the day month and year are Integers. The field references are strings by their names but the values in the database are integers

Comment: Would your method work if the prefixzero String Number was actually Integer Number in the prefixzero method?

Comment: You haven't given us the code where you are reading the COL values from the db. With autoboxing the int-method should work with integers as well - but only if you have never any null values. In this case you have to adapt the signature of `getDateStr()` to Integer or int as well, of course.

Comment: Sorry really am not with it at the moment noticed your last part of your post. Will try this and let you know

Comment: Just noticed you current comment , must have been typing mine as you did yours. The day month and year values will never be null so your methods should always work. As stated I will try this all out and let you know. Thanks for your input

Comment: Not getting any joy with this, if I leave the return values as string , the program crashes as it starts. if I sent the return values to Integer, it will not compile as the SQL requires string values.

Comment: I can see why it crashes the field name are not separated by a space and so they come across as COL_FIELD2COL_FIELD3COL_FIELD4 , will change the return code to include a space

Comment: Got the code to run without the crash but it still is not prefixing the month and day where they are 1 digit. Going to using Log.v to capture what the values are from the getDateStr etc

Comment: You wanted without a space. You mentioned 20130101 somewhere in a comment. Also I've changed the prefixzero method. It had to be ` > 9` of course :-)

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my last reply. If I look at the logcat when it errors it simply shows the field names not the values of these without spaces and this is what makes it crash. I will post the error in my question soon it may be clearer to see it

Comment: Should that  >9 be >8 as a figure such as 20130101 is 8 digits long and to use >9 means that this figure would be included

Comment: Okay. COL_XYZ is a constant for the column. Do you have the values as well? Your question only contains hints as to what you want and to what is going on. Please provide your full Activity (and if necessary your data model). And BTW ">9" is for each number. That is for day-values > 9 you do not need the zero. It has nothing to do with the lenght of the resulting string.

Comment: When you say the values do you mean the actual field names or the values of these?, what I am trying to do is a global change to one field across the whole table so passing one value to this field would be pointless. This code is only being applied to the data model and the activity is only using the data model/DBAdapter to read from and write to. I am currently not at a point to post the code straight away but when I can, I will post the DBAdapter which is where this code is being used . There is a lot of code in the Activity and some of it will bear no relevance to this matter

Comment: Yes the COL references are constants, I thought I had added these to my post,perhaps I am loosing it :) . I do appreciate you looking at this by the way Wolfram do not take my comments the wrong way :)

Comment: DBAdapter has been added to my question / post now

Comment: This answer is based on a wrong assumption of what your question was about. Please forget about it :)

Comment: Okay , however thank you for your input on this Wolfram Rittmeyer  My reasons for doing this is down to trying to do a date range with the single fields in the table. However I have had some ideas on getting around that so I will give these ago of they solve my issue I will put this post as solved

Comment: You have seen that I've added another answer based on my (hopefully now) correct understanding of your question?

Comment: Sorry Wolfram not getting enough intake of sleep , didn't see that, I will give it a go considering you have made the effort of doing this for me. I will be back soon.....

Comment: Wolfram - added an error I get to my question when trying your latest answer

Comment: "Table" must of course be the name of your table. It's "log" from what the rest of your statement says.

Comment: Yes it is meant to be Log, I just stupidly changed it for some reason in this post

Comment: Just added to my post the SQL code I am using to do this and with another version with a different variant of it if this helps

Comment: Sorry, forget about the first `AS` part. `UPDATE log SET ... WHERE log.id = LogTemp2.id`

Comment: Ok thanks I will give it a go tonight and let you know, thanks again

Comment: Yep got it to work had to change Log.id to Log._id and made an error myself by added any extra , in the substr . Looks good I am now hoping it will solve my other problem. will mark your answer thanks again Wolfram